# Merge 2 arrays based on a key in Typescript (Angular 13)

Tags: typescript, angular13

I am having 2 arrays each having a common key "productID". I want to merge the 2 arrays based on the common field "productID".

- array 1:

  {productImageID: 1, productID: 1, productImage: 'asf'}
  {productImageID: 2, productID: 2, productName:'anx'}
  {productImageID: 3, productID: 3, productImage: 'bmd'}
- array 2:

  {productID: 1, productCode: 'A20292', uom: 'No', quantity: 23}
  {productID: 2, productCode: 'B8282222', uom: 'No', quantity: 20}
  {productID: 3, productCode: 'R29299922', uom: 'No', quantity: 98}

I tried using map, but I am getting an error "map is not a function"
"core.mjs:6494 ERROR TypeError: array1.map is not a function

Here is the code that I tried

```
`mergeById(array1:any, array2:any) {
  array1.map((itm:any) => ({
   ...array2.find((item:any) => (item.productID === itm.productID) && item),
   ...itm
 }));
 }`
```

I am stuck here and I want to merge both these arrays based on the matching "productID". Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please console.log array1

Comment: And please do not use the any type, otherwise you run into this issues during run time and not compile time.

Comment: Thank you, I am getting an error when I am not specifying the type (Parameter 'itm' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)). Console.log gives the array details as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are doing something wrong, using the function.

I defined the function

```
function mergeById(array1: { productID: number }[], array2: { productID: number}[]): { productID: number }[] {
  return array1.map((itm) => ({
    ...array2.find((item) => (item.productID === itm.productID)),
    ...itm,
   }));
}
```

See above what a mean with using correct types. Otherwise your IDE is unable to tell you on compile time if the type has map function or not.

And i used it the following way:

```
const array1 = [
    { productImageID: 1, productID: 1, productImage: 'asf' },
    { productImageID: 2, productID: 2, productName:'anx' },
    { productImageID: 3, productID: 3, productImage: 'bmd' },
];
const array2 = [
    { productID: 1, productCode: 'A20292', uom: 'No', quantity: 23 },
    { productID: 2, productCode: 'B8282222', uom: 'No', quantity: 20},
    { productID: 3, productCode: 'R29299922', uom: 'No', quantity: 98 }
];
console.log(mergeById(array1, array2));
```

The result seems to be correct.

What i see in you function is that you do not return something. Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: How do you load the data from the api? Did you parse it correctly? i am just thinking loud, maybe the result is still a string and not an array of objects

Comment: Thank you for helping. I can see the result from your data. But am not seeing the merged result with my api response. I could see the data in the below format and merging is not happening. Not sure, if I need to format the response data from api get
array 1: 
0: {productID: 1, productCode: 'A20292', productDesc: 'Anti-intrusion bar', uom: 'No', quantity: 23}
1: {productID: 2, productCode: 'B8282222', productDesc: 'Bumper - Exposed', uom: 'No', quantity: 20}
array2:
0: {productImageID: 1, productID: 1, productImage: '/9j/4A'}
1: {productImageID: 2, productID: 2, productImage: '/9j/4AA'}

Comment: loading api data to array -->  

  this.prodService.getProducts(this.mID).subscribe(data => {
      this.array1= data;
  });

Comment: I need some more could, but please still notice. The directly on line after you subscribe(...) the data (this.array1) is still null or not defined. Is you api online somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, its not there online. I am now developing the components. I could see the result when subscribed in console.log and the results are same as pasted above. I could see the row numbers as 0: , 1: .. in the array, when printed. May be, thats the reason....

Comment: Ah, i see. The result is not a real array. You need to fix the output of you api and / the way of loading. You could achieve this in ts by using Object.entries but i would suggest to update api / loading